# C# dynamicmethod iloffset missing in stacktrace from exception

Tags: c#, stack-trace, dynamicmethod

Seems StackFrame.ILOffset returns -1 for dynamic method in Microsoft.  Works ok with Mono under Linux.

```
public static string PrintExceptionStack (Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace (ex, true);
    foreach (StackFrame sf in st.GetFrames ()) {
        MethodBase meth = sf.GetMethod ();

        int iloffset = sf.GetILOffset ();

        // prints -1 for dynamic methods in Microsoft (VS 2017)
        // prints correct value with Mono in Linux
        Console.WriteLine (meth.Name + " " + iloffset);

        // this works in Microsoft (as well as Linux Mono)
        int natoffs = sf.GetNativeOffset ();
        Console.WriteLine (meth.Name + " " + natoffs);
    }
}
```

I tried the debuggable attribute stuff on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/02/03/debugging-dynamically-generated-code-reflection-emit but it didn't make any difference.

Also the MS doc for DebuggableAttribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled states that the runtime always generates native-to-iloffset for v2 and up, so it seems it should not be necessary in any case.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjittrackingenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Am I missing something or is it broken?
Thanks

Comment: doh - I forgot I patched mono a couple years ago to make this work.  Is it hopeless for Windows?